# Memcached miss on every fetch on Rails with Dalli gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, fetch

So I have this basic action, which is accessed by ajax call, and fetches the most popular post, stores them in the cache and then displays in the users view:

```
def trending
  @trends = Rails.cache.fetch('trends', :expires_in=>1.hour) { Post.trends.all }
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render :layout=>false}
  end
end
```

**config/development.rb**

```
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and enable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_view.debug_rjs             = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.cache_store = :dalli_store
```

Now the problem that I have is that on every fetch cache is missed. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the following variable to true
config.cache_classes = true